# Fluid force on an oscillating cylinder!

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

So I am looking at a cylinder oscillating up and down in oncoming flow. My equations are the Navier-Stokes and that of a modified oscillator.

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 y_s}{dt^2}+2\omega_s \gamma_s \frac{dy_s}{dt}+\omega_s^2 y_s = \frac{1}{\rho}C_y(u,p)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{du}{dt}+ (u-u_s) \cdot \nabla u + \nabla p = \frac{1}{Re}\Delta u
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot u = 0
\end{equation}

with initial conditions

\begin{equation}
u= (u,v) =\left(0,\frac{dy_s}{dt}\right).
\end{equation}

The fluid force takes the form
$$C_y(u,p)= \oint_{\Gamma_w}-pn_y+\frac{1}{Re} n_x\left[\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]+\frac{2}{Re} n_y\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}dx_w ,$$

where the integration path is around the cylinder itself.

[image: A picture to demonstrate]

I am unsure of a few things in these equations, why we that the $u-u_s$ in the Navier Stokes. Also, I am a little bit confused as to why the fluid force takes this form. At the boundary of the cylinder, we have that the normal stress must equation zero (in my opinion). If anyone can explain how to get this force (or if it is dodgy as is my instinct) I would be grateful.

Catherine xx

Comment: Hello, I have added the picture. What I want to know is where the fluid force is derived from, because I don't understand how that fluid force was obtained. If anyone could derived the force on the cylinder from the cylinder I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to calculate the force per unit surface in the $y$-direction you need to calculate

$$\dfrac{dF_y}{dA}=\boldsymbol{e}_y\cdot\left[-p\boldsymbol{n}-\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\boldsymbol{\tau}\right],$$

in which $\boldsymbol{n}=n_x\boldsymbol{e}_x+n_y\boldsymbol{e}_y$ is the outward unit normal vector and $\boldsymbol{\tau}=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^3\boldsymbol{e}_{ij}\tau_{ij}$ is the viscous stress tensor. By using 
$$\boldsymbol{e}_i\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{jk}=\left[\boldsymbol{e}_i\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{j}\right]\boldsymbol{e}_k=\delta_{ij}\boldsymbol{e}_k,$$

in which $\delta_{ij}=1$ for $i=j$ and $0$ for $i\neq j$, we obtain:

$$\dfrac{dF_y}{dA}=-pn_y-\boldsymbol{e}_y\cdot\left[n_x\boldsymbol{e}_x\cdot\boldsymbol{\tau}+n_y\boldsymbol{e}_y\cdot\boldsymbol{\tau}\right]$$
$$=-pn_y-\boldsymbol{e}_y\cdot\left[n_x\left(\boldsymbol{e}_x\tau_{xx}+\boldsymbol{e}_y\tau_{xy}+\boldsymbol{e}_z\tau_{xz}\right)+n_y\left(\boldsymbol{e}_x\tau_{yx}+\boldsymbol{e}_y\tau_{yy}+\boldsymbol{e}_z\tau_{yz} \right)\right]$$
$$=-pn_y-n_x\tau_{xy}-n_y\tau_{yy}$$
$$=-pn_y-n_x\left[-\mu(v_x+u_y) \right]-n_y(-2\mu v_y)$$
$$=-pn_y+\mu n_x(v_x+u_y)+2\mu n_yv_y$$

So by intergration we finally obtain:

$$F_y= \oint_{\Gamma_w}-pn_y+\mu n_x\left[\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]+2\mu n_y\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}ds ,$$

in which $ds$ is the surface element of the cylinder wall. Using characteristic parameters you can rewrite this into the nondimensional form, which you have written.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, how would we go about solving this integral?

Comment: It is useless until you are able to determine $p$, $u$ and $v$. After having obtained these I would parametrize the surface and then try to calculate it.

Comment: Okay, wouldn't p, u and v be obtained from the Navier-Stokes equations? I am having difficulty understanding what it means to solve the problem simultaneously.

Comment: At the first glance, I would not think that it is possible to solve this analytically. I guess you need to first solve the Navier Stokes equation for the first time step. Then use the solution to determine the force and then evaluate the change of $y_s$. Then solve the Navier equation again and so forth. It might help to consider the problem in stream function formulation such that you only have to consider one scalar equation instead of two momentum equations and the continuity equation. But this is not a good idea for numerical simulations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69208/discussion-between-catherine-drysdale-and-mryoumath).